# Use of undefined constant host - assumed 'host' error in paypal class (codeigniter library)

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using codeigniter library called paypal_class. Everything is fine, but at validate ipn function i get this error. `Use of undefined constant host - assumed 'host'` which must be the reason that mail is not being sent to the user. Nothing is returned.

I am new to paypal. So i hope for a detailed solution. Thank you. Please ask whatever other information you may require.

---

Error is at this line:

```
 $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host], "80", $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

where

```
$url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);
```

here is the ipn function:

```
    function validate_ipn() {

    // parse the paypal URL
    $url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);

    // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
    // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
    // script.
    $post_string = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
        $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
        $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
    // open the connection to paypal
    $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'], "80", $err_num, $err_str, 30);
    if (!$fp) {

        // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
        // will be in the log.
        $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
        $this->log_ipn_results(false);
        return false;
    } else {

        // Post the data back to paypal
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }

    if (preg_match("/VERIFIED/i", $this->ipn_response)) {

        // Valid IPN transaction.
        $this->log_ipn_results(true);
        return true;
    } else {

        // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
        $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
        $this->log_ipn_results(false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `host` to `$host`.

Comment: it gave me : Message: Undefined index:

Comment: change `$url_parsed[host]` to `$url_parsed['host']`

Comment: @NicholasPickering im still not recieving the mail.. :(

Comment: Then something else is wrong - either your server is not set up to be able to send mail, or your settings are incorrect. Either way there's an error somewhere. None of the code you've posted has anything to do with mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change this:

```
 $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host], "80", $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

to

```
 $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'], "80", $err_num, $err_str, 30);
```

then debug the returned value here do:

```
$url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);
var_dump($url_parsed);
```